# Class derived from another one templated on it

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Am trying to find the meaning, relevance, and usefulness of code like:

```
 template<typename T1>
  class cA{

  public:
    std::string id_str;

    cA(){
      id_str="cA class!!";
     ........
    };

  };

  template<typename T2>
  class cB : public cA<cB<T2>>{

  public:
    .......

    cB(){
      this->id_str="amaz2 babe" ;
      .....
    };

  };
```

More precisely, am not familiar with `class cB : public cA<cB<T2>>`. It seems like a no-ending loop... Can someone clarify such a use?

Comment: Seems pretty useless. `T1` is not used in the context of `cA` so there's no point in it being a templated class.

Comment: @Amadeus, yes as it is written.